# Are there any simple map data sources like world.dat

Tags: data, cartography

I recently came across this blog post www.gnuplotting.org/plotting-the-world/ that used a file that holds a basic map of the world. Is there a name for this kind of data. Also is there a repository of similar but higher resolution data.

Direct link to data:
www.gnuplotting.org/data/world.dat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The world.dat file is a file format specifically for GnuPlot.  I haven't heard of it in use anywhere else and I couldn't find anything.

In a more recent [blog post](http://www.gnuplotting.org/plotting-the-world-revisited/) on that same site, the author talks about updating the world.dat file with better data - specifically from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/).  Since the author starts with shape files, this same data flow could be used on pretty much anything as the shape file format is pretty ubiquitous.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own maps for gnuplot from image files or shapefiles by using the R package [Rgnuplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rgnuplot/index.html).

It can also plot in a dozen cartographic projections